# Reference cells in another sheet using text in current sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell, excel-indirect

I need to get numbers from cells in other sheets. I am currently doing the following in Sheet 1 in cell D14 (but also in another 100 cells):

```
=('Sheet Two'!$AA$69*'Sheet Three'!AA$70)
```

This gets me the information I need. As it happens though I have a cell in Sheet 1 with the names of the sheets I need the information from.
I would like a formula that references the cells in Sheet 1 to get the names so I wouldn't have to manually type in the different sheet names for 100 cells.

So if say I have written in text:

```
Cell A1: Sheet two
Cell A2: Sheet Three
```

I need something like:

```
=(***Name in Cell A1***!$AA$69*'***Name In Cell A2***'!AA$70)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=INDIRECT(INDIRECT("A1")&"$AA$69")*INDIRECT(INDIRECT("A2")&"$AA$70")` seems to be of the nature of what you are asking for (where `A1` contains `''Sheet Two'!` but it looks as though a different layout might be much more effective, or use of Search and Replace.

Comment: I currently use search and replace.But I wish for a more automated way of doing it. I will attempt this and update you.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `INDIRECT` formula as pnuts suggested, but simpler like this:

```
=INDIRECT("'",A1&"'!AA$69")*INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!AA$70")
```